# How to make loop for this part of code in Python, to return me again to selection of login option

Tags: python-3.x, loops, authentication, selenium-webdriver, bots

```
print("********************Welcome To The AppBot!********************")
print("Select the account:\n0:Instagram\n1:Facebook\n2:Twitter\n3:Github\n4:DeviantArt\n5:KupujemProdajem\n6:Exit")
choice = int(input("For which account you need to login:"))

if choice==0:
   mybot = InstaBot(instausername,instapw)
   mybot.inslogin()
elif choice==1:
   mybot = FbBot(fbusername,fbpw)
   mybot.fblogin()
elif choice==2:
   mybot = TwitterBot(twitterusername,twitterpw)
   mybot.twlogin()
elif choice==3:
   mybot = GithubBot(githubusername,githubpw)
   mybot.ghlogin()
elif choice==4:
   mybot = DeviantArtBot(devartusername,devartpw)
   mybot.devlogin()
elif choice==5:
   mybot = KupujemProdajemBot(kupujemprodajemusername,kupujemprodajempw)
   mybot.kplogin()
else:
   pass
```

As I said I want this to go on loop to make every time to return to option to chose again should you log in or exit. Can someone explain to me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `while` and return `True` when you logged in from the `mybot` methods or manually set the variable.

```
is_logged_in = False

while not(is_logged_in):

    print("********************Welcome To The AppBot!********************")
    print("Select the account:\n0:Instagram\n1:Facebook\n2:Twitter\n3:Github\n4:DeviantArt\n5:KupujemProdajem\n6:Exit")
    choice = int(input("For which account you need to login:"))

    if choice==0:
        mybot = InstaBot(instausername,instapw)
        mybot.inslogin()
        is_logged_in = True

    else: pass
```

Comment: So if I understood your answer, I have a simple app that asks you to choose which platform you wish to log in. And when I chose it to log in and it ends there. When I close the browser or page and I want again to chose I cannot do it without reopening the app. So what should I do? Implement your solution or I need some more methods to return me to option to chose again. And then you so much for your effort and time :)